# rmagick on OSX Mavericks - "Can't find Magick-config in ..."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, imagemagick, homebrew, rmagick

When I try to install `rmagick` on OSX Mavericks, I get this error:

```
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
checking for /usr/bin/clang... yes
checking for Magick-config... no
Can't install RMagick 2.13.2. Can't find Magick-config in /opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin:/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/bin:/Users/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin:/Users/adam/.rvm/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:#/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql-5.6.13-osx10.7-x86_64/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/opt/ImageMagick/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin

*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rmagick-2.13.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.0.0/rmagick-2.13.2/gem_make.out
```

In `~/.bash_profile` is following:

```
MYSQL=/usr/local/mysql/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$MYSQL
#export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql/lib/
export PG_DUMP="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/"
#PATH=$PG_DUMP:$PATH
#export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/local/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH"
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

There's no such a path as is in the error output, where does it comes from and how can I fix it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have ImageMagick installed? Install it via [homebrew](http://blog.paulopoiati.com/2013/01/28/installing-rmagick-in-mac-os-x-mountain-lion-with-homebrew/):

```
brew install imagemagick
```